# After installing tightvncserver, I can't log in locally anymore

Tags: tightvncserver

I'm new to linux world, and I'm trying to set up a computer for a small office on a quite old computer.

I setup Lubuntu with some office apps (LibreOffice, ...) and it's working.

I'm now trying to setup a remote access for administrative support and/or user assistance.

SSH is setup and is working. I'd like also a remote GUI access. My bet is that VNC is the answer. But it's not as easy as windows to allow remote access (a single checkbox!). So my question are:

1. I installed tightvncserver, but there are plenty of vnc server software. Which one is suited?
2. now I've setup tightvncserver, I also created an /etc/init.d/vncserver script to always run tightvncserver. This is working, I can remotely access the computer. **However**, I can no more login to the computer locally :(. Each time I try to log, the screen blink, some text scroll and the login prompt reappears.
3. when accessing remotely, I only have the vnc password to type. I don't have the user's prompt.

Basically, I'd like to mimic the behavior of teamviewer. I'd like to replicate the screen, whether or not a user is loggued in. And it's where I'm stuck.

Thx for any help

Answer (score 0):

Regarding item #2 (cannot log in locally after installing tightvncserver), the steps I used to fix this issue were:

- Restore previous user's login state by putting the user back into the "nopasswdlogin" group via  `usermod -a -G nopasswdlogin`   (this was a test box, don't worry). This isn't necessary if you weren't bypassing password prompt initially. You can check this issue in /var/log/auth.log.
- Move  `.Xauthority`  file in user's home directory out of the way and chmod the user's home directory perms to 777 (not sure if that is needed). Not sure how you verify if this one is the problem, but this worked. Note that this step probably undoes whatever security the installer tried to put in, so you have to be careful here.

Note: I got the .Xauthority tip from 
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=27905